# Correct method to swap two rows in the SWT table

Tags: java, swt

I am using the SWT library in my software, not in Eclipse. I need to swap two rows at runtime in a table SWT that I populated via an array. I used the following method:

1. I take the array
2. swap two elements(with Collection.swap)
3. I empty the table
4. I reinsert the elements from the array

I'd like to know if there is a better method, do I have to reinsert all the elements in the table? because when there are so many rows the visual effect is evident and it seems a waste since I would like to swap only two rows at a time.

Here is the code:

```
    if(table.getSelectionIndices()[0]<table.getItemCount()&&table.getSelectionIndices()[0]>0) {
                    Collections.swap(pluginsTmp, table.getSelectionIndices()[0], table.getSelectionIndices()[0]-1);
                    int nextSelectionIndex=table.getSelectionIndices()[0]-1;
                    updateTable();
                    table.setSelection(nextSelectionIndex);
                }
```

In this case it serves to "go up" the selected item, exchanging it with those above

```
    public void updateTable() {
            table.removeAll();
            for(int a=0;a<pluginsTmp.size();a++) {
                Plugin p = pluginsTmp.get(a);
                TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
                item.setText(0,p.getClass().getName().toString());
                item.setText(1,p.getVersionMajor()+"."+p.getVersionMinor()+"."+p.getVersionBuild());
                item.setText(2,p.getAuthor());
                item.setText(3,(p.isEnabled())?"Enabled":"Disabled");
                item.setData("className",p.getClass().getName().toString());
                item.setData("status",(p.isEnabled())?"1":"0");
            }
        }
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Just call `setText` and `setData` on the two table items that have changed.

You can get an existing `TableItem` from the table using

```java
TableItem item = table.getItem(index);
```

where `index` is the row in the table.